# Using Taylor's Theorem to prove the second derivative test for maximum

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with
>    $a<b$. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $C^2$ on $(a,b)$.
>    Suppose there exists $x^* \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x^*) \ge f(x)$ for
>    all $x \in [a,b]$. Using Taylor's Theorem, show that $f'(x^*) = 0$ and
>    $f''(x^*) \le 0$.

Could someone check if my reasoning is right in my following proof?

Taylor Theorem's states that $f(x^*+h) = f(x^*) + f'(x^*)h + o(|h|)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ which implies that $f'(x^*) = \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h} - \frac{o(|h|)}{h}$ as $h \rightarrow 0$. So, 
$$f'(x^*) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h} - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{o(|h|)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h} $$

$f(x^*+h) \le f(x^*)$ by our initial assumption so $f(x^*+h) - f(x^*) \le 0$. We also know $f'(x^*)$ must exist since $f$ is $C^2$, so $f'(x^*) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h}$. If $h$ approaches $0$ from the right, then $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h} \le 0$ and if $h$ approaches $0$ from the left, then $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0^-} \frac{f(x^*+h) - f(x^*)}{h} \ge 0$, so the only way for equality to hold is if $f'(x^*) =0$.

To show that $f''(x^*) \le 0$, again by Taylor's Theorem we have:
$$\frac{1}{2}f''(x^*) = \frac{f(x^*+h)-f(x^*)}{h^2} - \frac{o(|h|^2)}{h^2} $$
as $h \rightarrow 0$. But $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}\frac{o(|h|^2)}{h^2}=0$ and $h^2$ is always positive so $f''(x^*) \le 0$.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct.